# read | deliminator file and extract variable in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a txt file with deliminator "|", and then extract the second and third variable.
so the data looks like this:

```
a|bb|cc|   
aaa|b|cccc|
```

and I want to create a data with only the second and third variable:

```
bb  cc
b cccc
```

any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        col2, col3 = line.split('|')[1:3] # get 2nd and 3rd column
        print col2, col3 # this could be written to a file if needed
```

will give you

```
bb cc 
b cccc
```

where `data.txt` is your data file.

*Explanation*:

You read the file, line-by-line, [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) each line with the `|` delimiter, and print the 2nd and 3rd element on each line. This data could also be written to a file, or manipulated further.

Comment: @user1615275 updated my answer to accommodate the newlines that weren't apparent in your original post before the edit.

Comment: And for good measure, maybe add a test on the row's length somewhere so you don't raise an `IndexError` ?

Comment: @PierreGM Yes I agree with you that ordinarily this would be a good idea, but since OP indicated and provided a regular dataset and didn't mention the possibility of irregularities, this meets their requirement with the data given (but of course could be easily adjusted if OP indicated otherwise). Thanks for the suggestion, let's see if we hear from OP

Answer (score 2):

Use the `csv` module

```
import csv
input = csv.reader(open('your_file.txt', 'rb'),delimiter="|")
for row in input:
    print row[1:]
```

This will print out each of the other values in each row aside from the first one. You would of course do whatever processing you wanted to do instead where I've printed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module with an appropriate dialect, then slice the resultant list per line and output it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module. Simple and elegant.